# how to reduce main.*.js file after build of angular 7 project?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, build

After building angular 7 project our main.*.js file size is 8.8 mb. We are already using gzip compression.Can you suggest how can we reduce its size so that it doesn't take more time to load?

Comment: I would suggest you use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer to figure out what is taking too much space. I'm not very familiar with angular, but if there is a webpack.config.js file (or similar name), you can checkout this page for optimization: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/ . You will also need to use [dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) to reduce initial js delivered, therefor speed up page loading times.

Answer (score 1):

you need to divide you components to modules then use module lazy loading this will take these component source to single module and loaded separably from `main.*.js`

Answer (score 1):

build with aot mode:`ng build --aot`

or

```
ng build --prod
```

more in [cli docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)

see also the new Angular engine (in recent versions): [ivy](https://angular.io/guide/ivy)

Comment: "scripts": {
        "build:ssr": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=42000 npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
        "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod --aot --optimization --build-optimizer --vendor-chunk --common-chunk --extract-licenses --extract-css --source-map=false && ng run angular.io-example:server",
        "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",    },

Comment: After using the above script also vendor js file is 15 mb